# How to do a Git pull request on remote branches via the command line

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge, pull-request

I have a feeling i'm using the wrong words, or misunderstanding the words i'm using, which is making searching for what I want to do difficult.

Right now I have a Git repo with 3 branches hosted on Azure Devops (very similar to Github/Gitlab/Bitbucket etc).

My current flow is to commit and push locally (using PHP Storm) and then login to Azure Devops and manually use their UI to do a pull request from my `develop` branch to my `staging` branch. Then I log into the server and git pull from the `staging` branch.

I have three branches in total `develop`, `staging` and `production`.

But on my local machine I only ever have `develop`, the others only exist on the remote server. I just work in `develop` and push to `origin/develop` and then do a pull request from `develop` into `staging` and then `production` when ready.

I figure there must be a way to write a script to do all of this at once and not have to log into Azure Devops or the server.

To summarise my question as simply as possible:

I currently have to log into Azure Devops and perform the following actions:

1. Login to Azure Devops
2. Click branches
3. Click "New Pull Request" next to the `staging` branch
4. Write a commit message (actually labelled "title")
5. Click "Complete"
6. Click "Complete Merge"

I would like to avoid logging into Azure Devops and be able to achieve this via the command line. Is this possible?

## UPDATE

I've found I can basically do what I want by logging into the server and doing:

- `git pull` (this will pull the latest develop even though i'm in staging
- `git merge origin/develop` (this will merge develop into staging locally)
- `git push` (this will update the remote staging)

This works perfectly although the one downside is that there doesn't seem to be a way to track how far behind `staging` is from `develop`, something which is provided by the azure devops UI.

Comment: There is an API for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 - I have absolutely no XP with it. But someone might have already wrote a command line utility using the api (something equivalent to the [hub command line](https://github.com/github/hub)...)

Comment: @Zeitounator Ah does it have to be done via Azure api, that would require extra authentication etc? I assumed it could simply be done via git commands.

Comment: An option would be to orchestrate it through a pipeline.  With conditional steps to do the creation and completion of the PR via the API, based on say your commit messages. $Build.SourceVersionMessage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found I can basically do what I want by logging into the server and doing:

`git pull`

(this will pull the latest develop even though i'm in staging

`git merge origin/develop -m "My commit message"`

(this will merge develop into staging locally)

`git push`

(this will update the remote staging)

You need to have develop locally as well for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

There's an Azure command line client which you can use to [create a pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest), but not merge one.  If you want to merge it as well, you'll need to use the API as Zeitounator mentions.

Depending on what you want to do, you may be able to use the `azure repos pr update` command with `--auto-complete` to make it merge automatically when you're happy with it as a workaround.

Comment: Ah does it have to be done via Azure api, that would require extra authentication etc? I assumed it could simply be done via git commands.

Comment: Pull requests are not a native Git concept.  They're something built on top of it by various platforms.

Comment: That would make sense why i've had such a hard time googling it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are multiple ways to create a Pull request in Azure DevOps. Such as:From the Pull Requests page on the web,Team Explorer in Visual Studio, The Development section in a linked work item.

`What you are looking for is creating pull request from Git Bash into Azure DevOps.`

We could expand the Git aliases with VSTS CLI commands to achieve it.

There is [VSTS CLI interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/install?view=vsts-cli-latest) that we could [configure to use git aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/vsts/git?view=vsts-cli-latest) including creating pull requests.

For the details, you can check this document:

[Visual Studio and Azure DevOps Git: Extend the git command line with server commands–Part 2](http://hermit.no/visual-studio-and-azure-devops-git-extend-the-git-command-line-with-server-commands-part-2/)

Besides, you could also create a PowerShell script to streamline the process. Basically what you need to do is:

> - Get the Azure DevOps access token
> - Pass the token to the PowerShell and let it run the setup steps.
>
>   You can check out the details here
>
> [Git Hub Repo](https://github.com/HainanZhao/Git-Azure-Devops)

Comment: I've been trying to figure out what the benefit of doing a pull request is vs a merge, it seems like my update to my question does exactly what I want. I think i've just be sidelined by the term "Pull Request" in the web client.